# Copy Formula from one workbook, paste as value in the Active workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The source range P22:P35 is formula.

This copies the formula:

```
Sub somemodule()

Set Src = Workbooks("Abc")
Sheets("Thissheet").Select
Src.Sheets("Thatsheet").Range("P22:P35").CopyRange("Q5")

End Sub
```

I want to paste only values.

I tried this:

```
Src.Sheets("Thatsheet").Range("P22:P35").CopyRange("Q5").PasteSpecial
```

It gives Run-time Error '1004'

I tried this:

```
Src.Sheets("Thatsheet").Range("P22:P35").CopyRange("Q5").PasteSpecialxlPasteValues
```

It gives compile error: Expected End of statement.

How do I copy values into the active sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid copy/paste. It's slow, it's tedious, and it's not worth it.

```
Dim srcRng As Range, tgtRng As Range
Set srcRng = Workbooks("Abc").Worksheets("SheetName").Range("P22:P35")
Set tgtRng = Workbooks("Tgt").Worksheets("SheetName2").Range("P22:P35")
'======================================================================
'====== MAKE SURE YOU USE CORRECT WORKBOOK/WORKSHEET NAMES ABOVE ======
'======================================================================

tgtRng.Value = srcRng.Value
```

Comment: The number of cells I copy/paste is so minimal, so it will not be slow. I am wondering, if it is not possible to copy, paste value.

Comment: It works, but considering speed is not an issue, and I already have a mix of source cells with Values and formulas, and prefer to retain the Active sheet reference, and for further knowledge on this, I wonder if it is not possible to COPY PASTE value in the method I have attempted. Thank you for the alternative solution.